# Views Children Not found

Tags: c#, wpf, children

We have an application which has a startup dialog which is a bit clunky and doesnt look the best. Within this dialog we house a Tab Control which holds a WebView2 which we use for Authentication (using Auth0).

We want to strip back all of this dialog and only have a window which displays the WebView2 object. So I have pulled everything out and am left with the following:

```
<Window x:Class="App.Windows.Views.AuthenticationDialog"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:wv2="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Wpf;assembly=Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Wpf"
        mc:Ignorable="d" Style="{DynamicResource ThemedDialog_Window}" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" WindowStyle="None"
        Title="Authentication" Name="Authentication" Height="600" Width="540">

  <Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/UI.Windows;component/Style.xaml" />
  </Window.Resources>

  <i:Interaction.Triggers>

    <i:KeyTrigger Key="Escape">
      <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding QuitCommand}" />
    </i:KeyTrigger>

  </i:Interaction.Triggers>

  <Grid>

    <wv2:WebView2 DefaultBackgroundColor="Transparent"
                  CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted="SigninWebView_InitialisationCompleted"
                  Name="signinWebView" />

  </Grid>

</Window>
```

The issue I am facing is that in order to wire up the WebView2 to our authentication/tokenisation mechanism we use an object tree service to find the child objects of the Parent (window). This mechanism worked fine in our old setup, but in the updated window, the FindChildRecursively method is telling me that the window has 0 children, so the WebView2 control is never located.

Why would the children of the Parent not be found when I call FindChild using this call:

```
var webView = _objectTreeService.FindChild<AuthenticationDialog, WebView2>("signinWebView");
```

```
    public TChild FindChild<TParent, TChild>(string childName)
       where TParent : DependencyObject
       where TChild : DependencyObject
    {
        var parent = _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<TParent>() ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Parent cannot found!");

        var foundChild = FindChildRecursively<TChild>(parent, childName);

        return foundChild ?? throw new InvalidOperationException($"Specified child not found! Child name: {childName}");
    }

    private static T? FindChildRecursively<T>(DependencyObject parent, string childName)
       where T : DependencyObject
    {
        T? foundChild = null;

        var childrenCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);

        for (var i = 0; i < childrenCount; i++)
        {
            var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);

            // If the child is not of the request child type child

            if (child is not T)
            {
                // recursively drill down the tree
                if (child != null)
                    foundChild = FindChildRecursively<T>(child, childName);

                // If the child is found, break so we do not overwrite the found child. 
                if (foundChild != null)
                    break;
            }
            else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(childName))
            {
                // If the child's name is set for search
                if (child is FrameworkElement frameworkElement && frameworkElement.Name == childName)
                {
                    // if the child's name is of the request name
                    foundChild = (T)child;
                    break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // child element found.
                foundChild = (T)child;
                break;
            }
        }

        return foundChild;
    }
```

Comment: Why do you access the _serviceProvider in your code? That's not good for several reasons. It looks like the returned instance is not the instance that is currently rendered. Therefore, it has no visual tree. You must use the current AuthenticationDialog instance to start the search.

Comment: The ObjectTreeService is a bit of legacy code really. 
I want to move away from all of this and utilise the Auth0.WPF extension, but this would require quite a large re-write of our Authenitcation and Tokenisation mechanism which is not in scope at the moment, so the initial approach was to utilise what is already there, so hence only changing the View at this time

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with the authentication procedure. It's never ok to use the IoC container in your code other than for the initial configuration. Again, you need the original instance of the current `AuthenticationDialog`. Unless the service provider is configured to return a shared instance you will get a new instance every time you make a service request. The problem you describe 100% fits the scenario that you were inspecting the wrong instance.

Comment: I do have the Dialog declared as a Singleton so I assumed this would only ever have a single instance

Comment: Have you ensured that the controls are properly loaded? Can please provide more context/details?